# Proving this relation is a function

Tags: relations

I want to prove that this relation in $\Bbb R$ is a function. 
$$(x,y)\in\mu\iff|y|\le|x|\le1$$

I know that for a function that for every $x$ there is only $y$. I also know I can't disprove it, so how can I prove it is a function?

Comment: For $x=1$ we have e.g. $|1/2| \le |x| \le 1$ and also $|1/3| \le |x| \le 1$; thus : $(1,1/2) \in \mu$ and $(1, 1/3) \in \mu$...

Comment: Maybe you first figure out how to do your other relation here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1975509/proving-a-relation-is-function
Then this one becomes easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't prove it, because it is false. In fact, it is easy to disprove that this is a function: clearly both $(1,0) \in \mu$ and $(1,\tfrac12) \in \mu$, so this is not a function.